# there exists an infinite number of values such that $3n+1 \mid 2^n-1$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

> Prove that there exists an infinite number of values $n \in \mathbb{N}^*$ such that $3n+1 \mid 2^n-1$.

I tried constructing a number with such property using $n,m$ such that $3n+1 \mid 2^n-1$ and $3m+1 \mid 2^m-1$. I also thought about using polynomials, but I failed.

Examples of $n$ that works: $10, 14, 36, 42, 52$.

Comment: Can you list the first few $n$ that work?

Comment: @lulu 10, 14, 36, 42, 52, 74, 76, 92, 94

Comment: @the_fox  Thanks!

Comment: Hmm, that sequence is not (yet) in the OEIS....

Comment: Worth noting:  in each of those cases $3n+1$ is prime.

Comment: @lulu That's usually the case, but not always. The first occurrence is $n=576$.

Comment: $n$ has to be even, so basically it is about checking $6n+1 \mid 4^n-1$

Comment: If you can show there are infinitely primes of the form $3n+1$ for which $2$ is a cubic residue, you've got it, since $2\equiv x^3$ implies $2^n\equiv x^{3n}\equiv1$ mod $3n+1$ if $3n+1$ is prime.

Comment: @BarryCipra  If we assume Euler's conjecture, this boils down to show that there are infinite many primes of the form $a^2+27b^2$